# The transaction is currently under review

Tags: authorize.net

I have been working to integrate our site with Authorize.net, and had a question about a particular response type. In the documentation, there are four possible response types:

1. The transaction has been approved
2. The transaction has been declined
3. There was an error processing this transaction
4. The transaction is being held for review

The first three response types are clear. My question is pertaining to the last one: transaction being held in review.

I checked the status descriptions on the Authorize.net portal, and it says that reviews could  occur only for eCheck.Net transactions and I am performing the eCheck.Net transactions. In the merchant account I am checking this transaction with "Under Review" this status but there is no way to approve this transaction.

I have also checked "Advanced Fraud Detection Suite" but this transaction is not listed under this page.

Right now I am working on a sandbox account with following details:

```
Test Routing Number:021000021
Test Account Number:111111111
Test Name on Account:Demo
Test Account Type:Checking
```

I want to see the successful response under sandbox account after that I will move on the live account.

Comment: Are you asking how to approve that transaction?

Comment: @JohnConde  I don't want the payments to go  under review. If any case payments goes under review then how can I approve the payment.

Comment: The payment is not under review from you. It's under review from the bank. They approve it, or decline it. When they do you will be notified.

Answer (score 0):

Echeck transactions work differently if compared to card payments. Authorize.net offers both payment instruments but the gateway is the same.

In case of echeck the transaction has to be approved by the RDFI and Nacha. It takes few hours for the transaction to go through. Most of the times in 24 hours funds move from RDFI to ODFI account.